# Return only unique rows from a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, not-exists

I have a table with 4 columns and 7 rows.

[image: this is my table sample]

This table contains 1 customer with the same ID same `LNAME` and `FNAME`.

Also the table has 2 customers with the same ID, but different `LNAME` or `FNAME`.

That is the sales reps input error. Ideally my table should have only 2 rows (Row with ID_pk 3 and 7)

[image]

I need to have the following result-sets from the above table:

1. All **unique rows** by all the four columns (**Row with ID_pk 3 and 7**). (*excluding case # 3 listed below*)
2. All **duplicates** by all the four columns (**Row with ID_pk 3 and 8**).
3. All duplicates by Customer_ID but with not matching LNAME and/or FNAME (**Row with ID_pk 1, 2, 4 and 5)**  (*these rows have to be sent back to sales reps for validation.*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing stuff this like relies heavily on nested queries, the GROUP BY clause, and the COUNT function.

Part 1 - Unique rows

This query will show you all the rows where the customer ID has matching data.

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME FROM dbo.customers WHERE Customer_ID IN (
    SELECT Customer_ID FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME FROM dbo.customers
        GROUP BY Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME
    ) Customers
    GROUP BY Customer_ID
    HAVING COUNT(Customer_ID) = 1
)
GROUP BY Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME
```

Part 2 - Duplicates

This query will show you all the rows that have the same data entered more than once.

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME
FROM dbo.customers
GROUP BY Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME
HAVING COUNT(Customer_ID) > 1
```

Part 3 - Mismatched Data

This query is basically the same as the first, just looking for a different COUNT value.

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME FROM dbo.customers WHERE Customer_ID IN (
    SELECT Customer_ID FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME FROM dbo.customers
        GROUP BY Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME
    ) Customers
    GROUP BY Customer_ID
    HAVING COUNT(Customer_ID) > 1
)
GROUP BY Customer_ID, Customer_FNAME, Customer_LNAME
```

Comment: Thank you so much Phillip. I was using Count, Group By, IN, Not Exists and nested sub-queries, but the sequence was off the track!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a CTE (Common Table expression): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

```
;WITH checkDup AS (
        SELECT Customer_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Customer ID) AS 'RN'
        FROM Table)
        SELECT Customer_ID FROM checkDup
        WHERE RN = 1;
```

Will give you your example output.

You may manipulate the CTE to get the other results you seek.